# has_one and has_many association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am a bit confused as to what to do with this association.

Models

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: payments
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: loan
end
```

The confusion comes in because theoretically a person can payoff the loan in one payment, thus, there wouldn't be 'many' payments.

Can Loan have both has_one and has_many at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Leave it as `has_many`. To find out if a Loan has been paid off, you'd simply sum the Payment amounts - it doesn't matter if it's only 1 or 100. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many` doesn't mean `must_have_many`, but rather `can_have_many`

In fact, your loan could have zero or a hundred payments, the relationship should still be `has_many`.

You will also still need to access the single payment as a collection of payments, even though there may only be one.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying Matt! I wasn't sure if has_many still holds true but now it sounds like it does.